# Node.js Instagram APISubscriptionError

Tags: node.js, instagram

I'm using the instagram-node module (found here: [instagram-node on GitHub](https://github.com/teleportd/instagram-node)
).

I understand that, upon making a subscription request, Instagram sends an immediate GET request to the passed callback.  I've tested my GET endpoint using a browser and Instagram's own example:

```
http://your-callback.com/url/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=15f7d1a91c1f40f8a748fd134752feb3&hub.verify_token=myVerifyToken
```

... it works just fine; I am logging req.query and see the full thing in the console and get the expected: `15f7d1a91c1f40f8a748fd134752feb3` output in the browser.

**BUT** when I make the subscription request to Instagram, I still ...

1. See no action on the callback endpoint
2. Receive this error:

`{ [Error: APISubscriptionError: Unable to reach callback URL "http://mydomain.co/geo/".]
  code: 400,
  error_type: 'APISubscriptionError',
  error_message: 'Unable to reach callback URL "http://mydomain.co/geo/".',
  retry: [Function] }`

The most frustrating thing is that this same exact code worked once ... so I greatly suspect something is jacked on the Instagram side ... too many self-absorbed teenage chicks posting mirror selfies, perhaps?

**Any ideas what might be wrong? -- Thank you!**

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    port = 80;

var ig = require('instagram-node').instagram();

ig.use({ client_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
         client_secret: 'yyyyyyyy' });

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/geo', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
});

app.post('/geo', function(req, res){
    console.log(req);
});

console.log('running subscription');
setTimeout(function(){
    ig.add_geography_subscription(32, -96, 500, 'http://mydomain.co/geo/', function(err, result, limit){
        if(err){ console.log(err); }
        else if(result){ console.log(result); };
    });
},100);

server.listen(port);
```

Comment: "http://mydomain.co/geo/" is that your domain?

Comment: No, but in my actual code I replace mydomain with my actual domain ;) ... like I said, I've verified the endpoint works / is public-facing.

Comment: Hey @DanShev did you ever manage to find a solution to this? Or did it just magically start working again?