# Instagram Unable to reach callback URL

Tags: instagram

I'm having weird problem that instagram won't allow me to subscribe to more tags. I subscribed yesterday to 3 tags without any problem, I tried today with new tag and no effect. Does somebody else have same problems?

I keep getting APISubscriptionError code 400 Unable to reach callback URL, but that URL is globaly accessible, even instagram is calling it every 5 min for tags i added yesterday.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having this too, every URL fails that I enter. Are they having issues?

Comment: +1 on this problem ... it would be nice if someone from the IG team would quickly respond (seeing as they claim they're using Stack as their platform for dev relations on their website...). (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951609/node-js-instagram-apisubscriptionerror)

Comment: I started having this problem a couple days ago. They must have changed how they handle urls, or it's different bug. I'm trying some different encoding/escaping now; i'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: At least its not just me. But this is odd. Even the Bug Tool link here is now broken! http://instagram.com/developer/support/

Comment: The whole thing is broken. Even submitting something here results in a broken page http://help.instagram.com/contact/364531043625021

Comment: @JakeN the Bug Tool link worked for me, but I thought it was broken at first as well. If you click the link it will take you to the Client Management screen, and there is a 'Report Issue' link at the top next to 'Register New Client'. I submitted one for the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997470/instagram-real-time-api-callback-url-escaping?noredirect=1#comment35152063_22997470

Comment: It works again, tested it 2 minutes ago, no changes in code.

Comment: Good catch mtaube - thanks. The answer posted by @capelio worked for me!

Comment: I've run an experiment and I believe they throttle subscription creations by IP address. I couldn't create a subscription from my EC2 instance last night, then I couldn't create one from my home network but I could from a cafe down the road. This is making me go crazy! I too have raised an issue with IG.

Comment: It's 2017 and I've got the same issue happening. It seems like #instagram haven't fixed anything. I'm getting "APISubscriptionError code 400 Unable to reach callback URL" and according to my logs the callback url isn't even being hit by the instagram servers. I've contacted them via their support but they don't reply.

Comment: @Francesco Same here, a month later. Did you ever manage to get it working?

Comment: @TimFletcher Not yet but I've raised it with Facebook developer support and they are looking into it. As soon as I know something I'll pass it on.

Comment: @Francesco Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This problem has now been fixed.**

If it re-appears, here is workaround that I developed dealing with similar problems with the real-time API over the past couple years.

Set your system up to use both the real-time API as well as the search API as a fallback. Ingest data coming through the real-time calls, but also periodically poll the search endpoint (either media/search or tag/search, depending on your application) for data you might have missed, ignoring IDs your system has already seen.

Your system will be much more resilient to issues with the Instagram API and also allow restarting your system periodically without missing data (since you can catch back up to real-time).

I keep track of "seen" Instagram IDs in a Redis set.

Comment: I'm also using safeguard, but that realy isn't the solution to that question. More and more I think that this is because of ssl "bug".

Comment: This is good, but for the actual act of subscribing the only option is to try again later.

Comment: @Shog9♦: sorry, but I still don't see any **fix**. I am encountering this problem for a few month now but nothing seems to actually help, but having a workaround.

Comment: @GameDroids Instagram is having API issues today. This is unrelated to the problem OP was having. https://twitter.com/gleamapp/status/648585821134684160

Comment: This problem is still ongoing at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I originally posted the below answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22997470/3037989) but thought I'd answer here as well since this question deals with essentially the same problem.

---

I've been having the same issue over the last few days. As a last ditch effort, I tried clearing all my subscriptions using the API, in case there were orphans running through the system. YMMV, but this ended up solving my "Cannot reach callback_url" problems.

The final section of the [Realtime Photo Updates](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) API docs has the details. To quickly test from the command line, give their curl example a go:

```
curl -X DELETE 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET&object=all&client_id=CLIENT-ID'
```

If this ends up working for you, I'd recommend updating your app code to delete any existing subscriptions for a given client_id before starting a new subscription. Of course, this is only viable if you limit yourself to creating one subscription per set of credentials. If you're creating more than one subscription, you'll need to keep track of the queries that make up your active subscriptions and delete those that already exist before recreating.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I wanted to register for a subscription.

Adding a AAAA record with the IPv6 of the server in the DNS of the domainname did the trick for me.