# Instagram API - Unable to reach callback URL

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I am having a lot of trouble with Instagram subscriptions.

I am trying to do this http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/

This is the curl request for the subscription;

```
$post = array('client_id' => 'abc',
'client_secret' => 'def',
'object' => 'tag',
'aspect' => 'media',
'verify_token' => '123',
'object_id' => 'cats',
'callback_url' => 'http://example.com/url/');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);       
curl_close($ch);
```

The callback url is remote, it is accessible worldwide, I can access it from my home and from my phone via 3G. So its online and live.

The code for handling the Pubsubhubub is, it simply checks for the query params and then outputs the challenge;

```
if(isset($_GET['hub_mode']) && $_GET['hub_mode'] == "subscribe")
{
    die(strip_tags($_GET['hub_challenge']));
}
```

But I always get this back

```
{"meta":
  { 
    "error_type":"APISubscriptionError",
    "code":400,"error_message":"Unable to reach callback URL \"http:\/\/example.com\/url\/\"."
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not alone.  I've been having the same problem since yesterday, and there's other [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951609/node-js-instagram-apisubscriptionerror/22955463#comment35080766_22955463) with the same [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956978/instagram-unable-to-reach-callback-url).